# Built Expo app crashes on start up: Didn't find class "host.exp.exponent.taskManager.ExpoHeadlessAppLoader"

Tags: android, reactjs, expo, native

When I'm trying to run my app built with React Native through Expo it crashes on the splash screen. It runs just fine if I boot it through the expo app on a real device or through an emulator. Logcat gives me the error:

```
 W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "host.exp.exponent.taskManager.ExpoHeadlessAppLoader"
```

I can't find any info on this error message, but I've seem to read that these types of issues are related to something with the package.json file. This is how mine looks like:

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-constants": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "package": "com.atlemlund.naturetracker",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "MY API KEY"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I have this error too, and for me it's not a misplaced api key

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Turns out that the error message had nothing to do with the crash. I had misplaced the API key. Moving it from package.json to app.json solved my issue.

Comment: What did you mean by mispalced the API, can you more precific please